# Which means " Gmail accounts with testing access " in google developer console

Tags: android, console

what is in google developer console:

License Testing

In addition to the owner of this console the following users will get the License test response from the application. There is a limit of 400 test accounts.
Gmail accounts with testing access

License Test Response

All accounts listed above will get the License Test Response. The account owner (but not the other test accounts) will also get this response for applications that have not been uploaded to Google Play yet.

I can not find anywhere else to describe why and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in Google Play Console->Settings->Developer account->Account details->License Testing. If you create an In-app Billing application, this area allows us to make a test order with a free purchase. For example, your google play account e-mail is "abc@gmail.com" and if you enter in license testing area, google allows you to buy item for free. By the way, you should upload your release apk to beta release field in google play console.